# Is there a working example of the AMP.DEV amp-link-rewriter?

Tags: amp-html

See https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/main/extensions/amp-link-rewriter/amp-link-rewriter.md for the documentation.

I added

```
<amp-link-rewriter layout="nodisplay">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "output": "https://open.tidalforce.org/opendata/all/us/salary" 
    }
  </script>
</amp-link-rewriter>
```

But it seems to have no effect.

Does amp-link-rewriter  REWRITE the page url?

This is a test page https://open.tidalforce.org/opendata/all/us/?parm1=salary#

I expect the page url to change to match the canonical url

https://open.tidalforce.org/opendata/all/us/salary